# Converting Boolean to Byte in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting

Why does casting a `boolean` to a `byte` in .NET give the following output?

Code Snippit:

```
Dim x As Boolean = 1
Dim y As Byte = x    'Implicit conversion here from Boolean to Byte

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print( _
    "x = " & x.ToString _
    & " y = " & y.ToString _
    & " (bool)(1) = " & CType(1, Boolean).ToString _
    & " (byte)((bool)1) = " & CType((CType(1, Boolean)), Byte).ToString)
```

Output:

> x = True
>   y = 255
>   (bool)(1) = True
>   (byte)((bool)1) = 255

Why does `True` (which commonly is referred to as an integer representation of 1) convert to 255 when casted to a `byte`?

Comment: I find it curious that VB.NET even lets you cast a Boolean to a byte. In C# that's an illegal cast.

Comment: If you do a `DirectCast()` in VB.NET it will automatically tell you that it is an illegal cast, but if you use `CType()` (which I have shown), it will do as above.  I'm interested to know how `True` which is commonly known as `1`, translates to `255` under the hood.  Lots of weird casting going on here.

Comment: I think this is just the behavior of the compiler. It emits the IL `ldc.i4 FF 00 00 00`, though I can't see anything in the spec that says why. For very simple cases the compiler is just optimizing away the cast.

Comment: How do you get it to emit the IL?  I can't figure out how to do that using ASP.NET in VS2010 =/

Comment: @vcsjones - I think Option Implicit in VB.NET will allow something like this.  Not 100% sure as I rarely work in VB.NET.

Comment: Use `Option Strict On` to disable the implicit conversions. Prefer `DirectCast` to `TryCast` because `DirectCast` will only cast, never convert

Comment: In many typed languages boolean False is just a wrapped all zero char (not wrapped as in the .NET boxing sense though), everything else is true. According to me .NET inherits more behavior from ADA, Smalltalk, pascal etc than from the C-language tree. I remember good ol' ADA where a bool could be instantiated with something else than true or false, heck that made my students confused =P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The VB.NET compiler handles it as a narrowing conversion. From the 10.0 VB.NET Spec:

> Narrowing conversions are conversions that cannot be proved to always succeed, conversions that are known to possibly lose information, and conversions across domains of types sufficiently different to merit narrowing notation. The following conversions are classified as narrowing conversions:
>
> - From Boolean to Byte, SByte, UShort, Short, UInteger, Integer, ULong, Long, Decimal, Single, or Double.

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx):

> When Visual Basic converts numeric data type values to Boolean, 0 becomes False and all other values become True. When Visual Basic converts Boolean values to numeric types, False becomes 0 and True becomes -1.

Byte's aren't signed, so you get 255 instead from [Two's Compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: This makes perfect sense now. -1 is such an odd choice IMO but explains perfectly why I'm getting weird 255 values in a poorly designed legacy DB using EF.

Answer (score 5):

A boolean value of `True` in .NET is stored as -1, which in turn is 11111111 due to [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

So `Dim x As Boolean = 1` converts 1 to Boolean True

and `Dim y As Byte = x` converts True to 11111111, which equals 255

(If instead you wrote `Dim z As Integer = x`, z would = -1)

Answer (score 3):

All historical versions of Basic I've seen which have supported bitwise Boolean operators with integers have used "all-bits-set", i.e. -1, as the value for true comparisons.  Thus, if one wanted to have a value that was 9 if a==b, or zero if not, one could use the expression `9 AND (a=b)`.  While the `?:` operator present in C allows such behavior to be coded more clearly, the use of -1 for "true" has more practical advantages than disadvantages in a language without a discrete Boolean type.

While vb.net is its own language, quite separate from vb6, there is a lot of code which has been ported from vb6 to vb.net, and may rely upon the fact that comparison operators yield all-bits-set when true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`, use:

```
Convert.ToByte(Boolean)
```

Link to documentation [Convert.ToByte(boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbd2w18f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Otherwise yo get the real value `-1`, `0xFF`.