# Converting bool to byte

Tags: c#

```
bool myBool = true;
byte myByte;
```

- This conversion runs `myByte = Convert.ToByte(myBool);`
- This conversion does not run `myByte = (byte)myBool;`

For a newbie(`me`): why are the above different?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217278/converting-boolean-to-byte-in-vb-net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Convert.ToByte` is a method - it can do whatever it wants to, probably along the lines of:

```
return input ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0;
```

A cast is a *language-level* operation. It requires that either the language knows about the conversion itself, or that one of the types involved has a user-defined conversion with the right input and output types. Neither of these is the case when converting from `bool` to `byte`.

Basically, the language doesn't define what that cast should mean, so the compiler prohibits it.

Comment: Why do you need to cast the 1/0 at all to `byte`? Actually ILSpy says that `ToByte` is implemented in the following way: `if (!value)
 {
  return 0;
 }
 return 1;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Otherwise the type of the expression would be `int`, so it couldn't be returned. It really doesn't matter though - those implementations are equivalent.

Comment: I just wondered why it works without casting (when the return type is `byte`), but i assume that the reason is that an `int` can be converted to `byte`implicitely. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter There is no implicit conversion from `int`to `byte`. However, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) states an exceptional case for int: "**A constant expression** of type int can be converted to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, **provided** the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type."